# How can I define a function after a series function

Tags: functions

Since I am new to Mathematica, I have no idea to define a function directly from the Series. For example, if I define

```
f1[x_] := Normal[Series[e^x, {x, 0, 5}]]
```

if I input any value, say 0,

```
Function[x, Series[e^x, {x, 0, 5}]][0]
```

it will give me warning that "0 is not a valid variable".

Hence, how can I build a pure function from Serie without any warning?

By the way, are there any recommended books for beginners to study the language in Mathematica? Since I find, reading helps does not really help me learn some new clauses, functions and language structure.

Thanks

Comment: [Shifrin's book](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org) is particularly nice.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some managing the order of operations is required here. `Normal[Series[E^x, {x, 0, 5}]` generates the right form, but the function argument replacement takes place before the series expansion normally, so:

```
Function[x, Series[E^x, {x, 0, 5}]][0]
```

Expands to:

```
Series[E^0, {0, 0, 5}]
```

Which should be fairly obviously nonsense.

Instead, we can tell *Mathematica* to evaluate the series during the definition of the function rather than *as part of* the definition of the function:

```
f[x_] := Evaluate[Normal[Series[E^x, {x, 0, 5}]]];
```

Then we can use this `f` normally, for example by calling `f[2]` to get `109/15`.

Please also note the use of capital `E` for the constant. All *Mathematica* built-ins start with capital letters, including `E`, `Pi`, and so on.

For information on books, I would recommend starting by looking at the [reference-request](/questions/tagged/reference-request) tag on this site.